# Put first boost::regex match into a string

Tags: c++, stdstring, boost-regex

Somehow, I've failed to find out, how to put only the first occurrence or regular expression to string. I can create a regex object:

```
static const boost::regex e("<(From )?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)>(.*?)");
```

Now, I need to match `([A-Za-z0-9_]+)` to `std::string`, say `playername`.

```
std::string chat_input("<Darker> Hello");
std::string playername = e.some_match_method(chat_input, 1);   //Get contents of the second (...)
```

What have I missed?
What should be instead of `some_match_method` and what parameters should it take?

Comment: Can you include an example string?

Comment: Its not my problem to match the occurrence, but to get the match results. So the string does not matter. I'll include it anyway.

Comment: Sure, but if you change the regex to `(?<=<(From )?)([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?=>(.*?))` you don't have to care about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're missing is that `boost::regex` is the regular expression, but it doesn't do the parsing against a given input.  You need to actually use it as a parameter to `boost::regex_search` or `boost::regex_match`, which evaluate a string (or iterator pairs) against the regular expression.

```
static const boost::regex e("<(From )?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)>(.*?)"); 
std::string chat_input("<Darker> Hello");
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;
if (boost::regex_match(chat_input, results, e))
{
     std::string playername = results[2];  //Get contents of the second (...)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
static const regex e("<(From )?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)>(.*?)");
string chat_input("<Darker> Hello");
smatch mr;
if (regex_search(begin(chat_input), end(chat_input), mr, e)
    string playername = mr[2].str();   //Get contents of the second (...)
```

Please note that regex is part of C++11, so you don't need boost for it, unless your regular expression is complex (as C++11 and newer still has difficulties processing complex regular expressions).